# TangoWithDjango | 6.2.3 Modifying the Index Template| cannot get the categories list

Tags: python, django

I'm currently working on the following tutorial http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book/chapters/models_templates.html

I am unsuccessful in generating the Rango's homepage with the following errors. I got all correct for all previous chapters.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 with Django 1.7

The error I got from generating the rango webpage were as follow:

Error during template rendering

In template /home/william/tango_with_django_project/templates/rango/index.html, error at line 10
Cannot resolve keyword 'likes' into field. Choices are: id, name, page

```
1   <!DOCTYPE html>
2   <html>
3   <head>
4   <title>Rango</title>
5   </head>
6   
7   <body>
8   <h1>Rango says...hello world!</h1>
9   
10  {% if categories %}
11  <ul>
12  {% for category in categories %}
13  <li>{{ category.name }}</li>
14  {% endfor %}
15  </ul>
16  {% else %}
17  <strong>There are no categories present.</strong>
18  {% endif %}
19  
20  <a href="/rango/about/">About</a>
```

I am working on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Here is the files and directory location /home/william/tango_with_django_project

```
- manage.py
- populate_rango.py
- tango_with_django_project [directory]
---- settings.py
---- urls.py
- rango [directory]
---- views
---- models.py
- templates [directory]
---- rango [directory]
-------- index.html
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Page(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    url = models.URLField()
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

**rango/viewspy**

```
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponse
from rango.models import Category

def index(request):
    # Obtain the context from the HTTP request.
    context = RequestContext(request)

    # Query the database for a list of ALL categories currently stored.
    # Order the categories by no. likes in descending order.
    # Retrieve the top 5 only - or all if less than 5.
    # Place the list in our context_dict dictionary which will be passed to the template engine.
    category_list = Category.objects.order_by('-likes')[:5]
    context_dict = {'categories': category_list}

    # Render the response and send it back!
    return render_to_response('rango/index.html', context_dict, context)
```

**templates/rango/index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Rango</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Rango says...hello world!</h1>

        {% if categories %}
            <ul>
                {% for category in categories %}
                <li>{{ category.name }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% else %}
            <strong>There are no categories present.</strong>
        {% endif %}

        <a href="/rango/about/">About</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

See the first bullet under section 5.10... The likes field in your Category model doesn't exist, but you are asking to order by that field in your view.

After creating the Like model and migrating you should be up and running :)

Comment: Many thanks for your comments, I got the it fixed after finishing the exercise in section 5.10